SwiftUI Map zoom to show custom annotations
I'm trying some basic tutorials for testing MapKit. I have added two custom annotations and the map automatically zooms out to show both annotation coordinates, but the annotations views are cut on the left and right margins. Is there a way to define a zoom level to initially show the full annotations views?
The code to replicate the issue:
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct Pin: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D
}

struct ProjectMapView: View {
    let locations: [Pin] = [
        .init(name: "New York", coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.712548889567415, longitude: -74.00637733127851)),
        .init(name: "Rome", coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.89682093385061, longitude: 12.482471453457123)),
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Map {
                ForEach(locations) { location in
                    Annotation(location.name, coordinate: location.coordinates) {
                        Color(.systemPink)
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                            .overlay { Circle().stroke(.white, lineWidth: 2) }
                            .shadow(radius: 4)
                    }
                }
            }
            .mapStyle(.hybrid(elevation: .flat))
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}

#Preview {
    ProjectMapView()
}

The result:


you could try using a Map(...) initializer that takes a bounds: MapCameraBounds
as parameter. See Map
